# extending smarty - make block name a parameter

Tags: php, plugins, smarty

I have a registered a block as a plugin for my smarty. The current block is used like the following:

```
{widget src="someWidgetName" options=[opt1=>val1]}
    {$widget->someFunction();}
{/widget}
```

Is it possible that I make the block look like:

```
{widget="someWidgetName" options=[opt1=>val1]}
    {$widget->someFunction();}
{/widget}
```

Comment: Do you have an example where you've seen this work? Your goal doesn't really make sense. It would be like `<div="blah"></div>`

Comment: No I haven't. This would've been useful because some widgets can have "src" variable which will cause a problem... I will need to find another way to deal with this.